# How do I recursively apply PKGREPOSITORY when calling make package-recursive in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports, make

I'm trying to create a package of Apache and its dependencies:

```
sudo make package-recursive \
__MAKE_CONF=~/make.apache22.conf \
PKGREPSOITORY=/usr/home/gvkv
```

Everything works fine; Apache and its dependencies compile and install and `apache22.tbz` is in `gvkv`.  The problem is that the dependency packages are built in their respective `ports/<package>` directories!  There are about fifteen of them and while it's easy enough to retrieve them with `find` and a `perl` one-liner, surely there must be a way to tell `make` to run in an environment such that the dependency packages end up in `gvkv`.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the fun of using FreeBSD is dealing with the ports subsystem.  It's good in many ways--easy installation and upgrading within the FreeBSD ecosystem but poor in others--setting variables via `make` configuration files or environment don't work as expected or even as advertised.

Nevertheless, [SirDice](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?p=98271#post98271) has come to the rescue with a neat little trick:

```
mount -t nullfs /directory/for/pkgs /usr/ports/packages
```

which is really cool because it bypasses the use of environment variables and you can set the destination directory for wherever you want.  Very helpful if you're (like me) using a 'build-jail' to make packages that are installed on different systems or other jails.

*The `/usr/ports/packages` directory is where `PACKAGES` points to (if it exists) which is supposedly able to point somewhere else but didn't work for me.  The `man` page stipulates setting `PKGREPOSITORY` which only works if you are building a single package.*

Answer (score 1):

I've read that that PKGREPOSITORY is dependent on PACKAGES.

You can set PACKAGES in `/etc/make.conf`. For example:

```
DISTDIR= /opt/portbuild/distfiles
PACKAGES=/opt/portbuild/packages
```

Comment: That's true--it works as long as there is only one package to build; otherwise, if you are also building the dependencies, they are written to their respective ports directories.

Comment: For us, the package and the dependencies are all written to /opt/portbuild/packages

Comment: Make sure the PACKAGES directory exists before running the make.